# How do I Create a Movable Type 5 Development Environment?

Tags: movabletype

I want to create a development environment running Movable Type 5.
To create a separate development environment, it is necessary to copy and paste to reflect production.
How would I go about building a good environment?

Comment: To change the design in the development environment, I want to reflect the production environment in a semi-automatic (one click if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying that you need a development environment for Movable Type, what exactly do you need to develop?
If you are developing a plugin? or theme? a website? content?

It is possible to assign a different mt-config.cgi file to each virtual server, and working on different database, for the same installation. 
If you are developing a plugin, you will want to use the PluginSwitch directive so the developed plugin won't be loaded on the real website.

http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/installation/managing-multiple-instances-of.html

Comment: To change the design in the development environment, I want to reflect the production environment in a semi-automatic (one click if possible).
PluginSwitch knew the first time. I'll use need to implement comes out, thank you.

Comment: maybe you should write a theme? then you will just need to apply it to the website in the production, and use rsync to upload it to the server.

Comment: I see, if I can be exported to rsync SQL. I'll try, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to build a development environment, and an experienced Movable Type developer would need to know more about your goals in order to make a good recommendation.

All of the following guidance assumes that Movable Type has been installed and is ready to run 
 on the development server.

Here are a few basic tips:

Although some of the key configuration details for a Movable Type instance are kept in mt-config.cgi, there are website-level and blog-level settings that are of equal importance that are kept in the underlying database.

Since most Movable Type 5 instances use MySQL as the database backend, it's possible to dump the entire contents of the Movable Type database using the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility or a more visual tool like the [Export function of phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faq6_4).  This produces a large text file with  MySQL [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) and [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statements.

Once the database is dumped to a file, the file can be moved to another server, modified, and reconstituted.  One of the tasks we commonly perform at that point is to go through the database using an editor, the UNIX sed command, or some similar process, and perform global searches and replacements for the URLs and file system paths that are embedded in the database dump.

This is necessary in many cases because your production website may be `http://www.mysite.com/`, but your development environment may be `http://dev.mysite.com/` or even `http://localhost/`.  Similarly, the file system paths in production may be /var/www/mysite/htdocs/... while development may be /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/....

Once changes of this nature are made and the modified file is saved, the database is reconstituted on the development server by using a UNIX shell command like:

```
cat mysite.sql | mysql -u mt_user -p mt_password
```

Or by importing the database into another copy of phpMyAdmin.

Once all of this is done, the mt-config.cgi file from production needs to be copied into the Movable Type working directory and rewritten so that several important elements are changed:

- CGIPath
- StaticWebPath
- Database
- DBUser
- DBPassword
- DBHost

These [Movable Type Configuration Directives](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/config-directives/) are discussed in the online documentation.

All of the non-database assets have to be copied from production to development.  Things like files containing jpeg, png, and gif images, files that have been placed in the production file system either manually, or using the [Asset Manager](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/author/manage-assets.html).  There may be other files that need to be copied from production, depending on how you use Movable Type.

Once all of this is done, and you are able to login to the Movable Type development server successfully, you will probably want to the websites and blogs to ensure that all of the content has been copied into development.

I hope these instructions are somewhat helpful to people needing to setup a development environment.  I would be happy to get comments or edits if anyone thinks I left out anything significant.

Answer (score 0):

Eslar, you may like to consider also this documentation resource:
http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/mt41/rsync.html

Alternatively, you may like to consider:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Answer (score 0):

If you go with the 'rsync' solution described in the movable type documentation, you may like to check also these configuration directives mentioned there:

http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/config-directives/rsyncoptions.html
http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/config-directives/synctarget.html